# Exce 2013l: Transpose header and count matrix

Tags: excel, matrix, transpose

Is possible generate dynamically a total-matrix from table? I have some students list with their courses marked (with "1" symbol):

[image]

I need transpose the header, and count how many students have two courses at the same time, for each course, like this:

[image]

Is it possible dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Step 1

Copy the headers. Assuming your first table is in the range A1:N25  We can start by generating our header row with the most basic of formulas and copying to the right as far as required.  In my example I placed the formula below in cell Q1.

```
=B1
```

## Step 2

Transpose the headers.   There is the transpose function, as well as the copy paste function, but I opted to go with a simple INDEX function.  In P2 I placed the following formula and copy down as far as needed.

```
=INDEX($Q$1:$AC$1,ROW(A1))
```

The ROW(A1) part acts as a counter as the formula is copied down and increases the column in the reference range Q1:AC1 to read from.

## Step 3

Count the number occurrences where there is a 1 in the column that matches the header up top, and a 1 in the column that matches the header on the left.  To do this I place the following formula in Q2 and copied down and to the right as far as required.

```
=IF(MATCH(Q$1,$Q$1:$AC$1,0)>MATCH($P2,$Q$1:$AC$1,0),"",COUNTIFS(INDEX($B$2:$N$25,0,MATCH(Q$1,$B$1:$N$1,0)),1,INDEX($B$2:$N$25,0,MATCH($P2,$B$1:$N$1,0)),1))
```

The first part of the IF checks so see if the count should be performed or if a blank value should be shown.

## Step 4

Bolding the text when the header up top is equal to the header on the right.  You can do this manually, or you can use conditional formatting.  The logical formula for conditional formatting would be:

```
=Q$1=$P2
```

Have the range Q2 to AC14 selected with Q2 being the active cell when you enter conditional formatting and select formula as your method.  after entering the formula select format, select the Font tab, and then select bold.

## Proof of Concept

[image: POC]